# jquery mouseout event

Tags: jquery

In this code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".main_image .desc").show(); //Show Banner
    $(".main_image .block").animate({ opacity: 0.65 }, 1 ); 
    $(".image_thumb ul li:first").addClass('active');  
    $(".image_thumb ul li").click(function () 
    {
        var imgAlt = $(this).find('img').attr("alt");
        var imgTitle = $(this).find('a').attr("rel");
        var imgDesc = $(this).find('.block').html();
        var imgDescHeight = $(".main_image").find('.block').height();

        if ($(this).is(".active")) 
        {
        return false;
        } 
        else 
        {
            $(".main_image .block").animate({ opacity: 0, marginBottom: -imgDescHeight }, 250, 
            function() {
                $(".main_image .block").html(imgDesc).animate({ opacity: 0.85, marginBottom:"0" }, 250 );
                $(".main_image img").attr({ src: imgTitle , alt: imgAlt});
            });
        }
    });
```

i have changed click with mouse over, but how can i set mouseout event?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see your mouseover event handler.

If you want a mouseover/mouseout handler, use hover() like so:

```
$('.myelement').hover(
function() {
    // my mouseover code
},
function() {
    // my mouseout code
});
```

**EDIT:**

OK, I think I understand. To bind a 'mouseout' event (or any event) do the following:

```
$('#myelement').bind('mouseout', function() {
    // my code
});
```

**PREVIOUS EDIT:**

If you are saying that you want to 'stop' the current animation, then you need to call `stop()`. Consider the following example:

```
$('#box').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).stop();
            $(this).animate({height:300}, 1000);
        },
        function() {
            $(this).stop();
            $(this).animate({height:100}, 1000);
        });

#box {
    background: orange;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

<div id='box'></box>
```

If the animation is in progress when you 'mouseout', calling `$(this).stop()` will halt the animation and start the 'mouseout' animation. If there is no animation for 'mouseout', then simply call `$(this).stop()`.

Comment: @patrick you are first star :)
I know this, hover or mouseover but i want to write a mouseout, for stop mouseover effects.

Comment: @jasmine - Unless I misunderstand you, that is exactly what `hover()` does. It takes two separate functions. The first gets called when you 'mouseover'. The second gets called when you 'mouseout'. Am I missing your point? **Now go check some boxes!  :o)**

Comment: @patrick;
I know the hover but;
There is an iamge rotator
http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/image-rotator/

But I want to change "click" to "hover".
But my friend that when you change "click" to "hover" and when you move the mouse from top to bottom, all tabs changed. He daid that you may use "mouseout" event.

Comment: @jasmine - I see. You need to bind the 'mouseout' event. See my new edit in the middle of my answer. You call `$('#myelement').bind('mouseout', function(){ // my code })`

Comment: I know the samples and examples from tutorials but i cant edit the above code.
Im not professional in jquery and this rotator code is very heavy for me :( 
Thanks for help

Comment: Ok, now can you please tell me what you wish to accomplish? It is good to post code (html and javascript) and also give a clear explanation of what the code should do, and what it is currently doing wrong.